# Search inside an array to see how many times each object has been used

Tags: arrays, typescript, for-loop, angular6

We have 2 arrays one is the AnswersList[] this contains all possible answers for questions.

we have split AnswersList[] into 6 separate Arrays {gender, age, disability, ethnic origin, religion, sexual orientation}. For this issue if we use genderList[].

The main array is EqualityAnswers[] this is of type IApplicantAnswers.

```
import {IAnswers} from "../Enum/answer.model";
export interface IApplicantAnswers {
    ApplicantAnswersKey: number;
    CompetitionKey: number;
    Gender: IAnswers;
    Age: IAnswers;
    SexualOrientation: IAnswers;
    Religion: IAnswers;
    EthnicOrigin: IAnswers;
    Disability:IAnswers;
}
```

what we want to be able to do is check in genderList[] which is also of type IAnswer

```
export interface IAnswers {
    AnswerKey: number;
    QuestionKey: number;
    Name: string;
    Description: string;
}
```

so what i want to do is for each type of genderList[i].AnswerKey i want to see how many people have selected that in the EqualityAnswers[].

initially i was looking at looping through genderList[] and then filter EqualityAnswers[].Gender.AnswerKey and return the length.

The issue is assigning this to an array of ResourceList

```
export class ResourceList {
    Name: string;
    Count: number;
}
```

called genderCountList: ResourceList[];

the idea is that genderCountList will be {name:"female", count:2}, {name:"male", count:5}, {name:"prefer not to say", count: 3}

then I will be able to use this to construct my tables dynamically. This will allow for us to add answers at database level.

The only issue is i have mind lock and cant think how to structure this.

Comment: my suggestion is use a Map (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map ) type type to group your answers ,  if you want to have this {name:"female", count: 3} for the map of gender the key should be sex and the value the count.. if the gender is not previously defined you going to insert a new pair in your map otherwise you will increment the count (value ), after you can generate the array

Comment: Thank you for your reply with this. So i'm a little confused. I would use it as follows 

` getGenderCount(): any {

       return this.genderList.map(function(item,index){
       // In here I then need to check if the item.Key is in the equalityData.Gender and how many times it occurs before storing it to a new array of item.Description and count
        return item;
    });
    }`

Comment: exactly.. In that way you going to traverse the loop only once and construct all your filtered results at the same time

Comment: Thank you for your help. I have put an answer up but if you wish to post the answer then i will select that as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So with the help from Ricardo which I am very grateful for I managed to get this working from his advice.

```
 getListOfGendersWithCount(): void {
        var self = this;
        this.genderList.map(function (item, index) {

            var gender = new ResourceList();
            gender.Name = item.Description;
            gender.Count = self.equalityData.filter(x => x.Gender.AnswerKey === item.AnswerKey).length;

            self.genderCountList.push(gender);

            return item;
        });
    }
```